# When sharing a file with external user can we disable MFA

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, multifactor-authentication

We have a SharePoint site collection which allow sharing with existing and new external users.

now we share a file with the eternal user as follow:-

[image]

[image]

where the external user will get this email with a link to open the file, as follow:-

[image]

after clicking on the link >> the user can select to get a code, as follow:-

[image]

after entering the code>> the user will get a MFA authentication.

so my question is how we can disable MFA for external users that we share the files with them? of course we want to keep MFA for internal users. is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Conditional Access policy that makes internal users require MFA and external users does not require MFA.

Here are steps:

1.Go to Azure Active Directory admin center -> Protect&secure -> Conditional Access -> New policy.

2.In the Users section:

[image]

[image]

3.In the Cloud apps and sections:

[image]

4.In the Grant section:

[image]

5.Enable policy.